# Cómo obtener el valor de dos claves en un arreglo de objetos con arreglos anidados en Angular?

Tags: array, angular, typescript, objeto

tengo un `arreglo` de objetos con arreglos anidados:

```js
categorias =
  [
    {
      0: 'agosto', 'Manuel': [
        {
          id: 12,
          categoria: 'sociedad',
        },
        {
          id: 13,
          categoria: 'sociedad',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      1: 'septiembre', 'Carlos': [
        {
          id: 14,
          categoria: 'deportes',
        }
      ],
    },
  ]
```

Necesito presentar en pantalla lo siguiente:

```
agosto, Manuel
12 - sociedad
13 - sociedad

septiembre, Carlos
14 - deportes
```

Necesito mostrar las dos claves que tengo en cada objeto. Estaba tratando de acceder hasta los datos, pero no consigo hacerlo.

```html
<div *ngFor ="let item of categorias | keyvalue"  >
  {{item.key}}  {{item.value}}
  <p *ngFor="let value of categorias[item.key]">
    {{ value }}
  </p>
</div>
```

Solo consigo de salida esto:

```
0 [object Object]
1 [object Object]
```

Cómo puedo hacer para mostrar los datos que necesito y ademas de ello si se presiona un botón obtener el valor de cada clave, por ejemplo si necesito mandar `agosto` y `septiembre` o `Manuel` y `Carlos` como parámetro en una función:

```js
funcion(key1, key2) {
  console.log(Key1, Key2)
}
```

Que en caso de seleccionar el primer objeto los valores serian:

```
agosto, Manuel
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo recomendable es formatear tu array, a una manera más manejable y evitarte lógica compleja en el HTML, si usas ese formato de data en varios lados, sería bueno usar un `pipe`, de lo contrario sólo bastaría con crear un método interno para llevar a cabo el formateo.

En tu caso, tienes un array de objetos. Y estos objetos tienen keys que usarás como data también, así que no sólo necesitarás iterar por los elementos, también por las llaves utilizando `Object.keys()`.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo completo:

```
formattedCategories = this.categorias.map((item) => {
  let month;
  let name;
  let data;

  Object.keys(item).forEach((entry, index) => {
    // First index is the month
    if (index === 0) {
      month = item[entry];
    }

    // Second index is the name but this time we need the key
    // and also its value gives you the data
    if (index === 1) {
      name = entry;
      data = item[entry];
    }
  });
  return { month, name, data };
});
```

Creo que el código habla por sí solo, pero de todas maneras lo explico. Aquí necesitaba acceder al índice de cada iteración de las `keys`, ya que no estaba seguro de si este formato será así siempre y, si lo es, siempre cumplirá que:

- La primera iteración tendrá el mes (value).
- La segunda el nombre (key) y el array de categorías (value).

Pero debes tener cuidado, aquí debes entender que las keys de un objeto están **ordenadas**, por eso es que se puede hacer eso.

Una vez formateado el array de objetos, el acceso sería más intuitivo:

```
<div *ngFor ="let item of formattedCategories"  >
  {{item.month }}, {{ item.name }} :
  <p *ngFor="let value of item.data">
    {{ value.id }} - {{ value.categoria }}
  </p>
</div>
```

Aquí te dejo un [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmlc4v?file=src/app/app.component.html) con esta implementación.

Comment: Entendí perfectamente lo que me explicas, y pues así resulta más simple acceder a los datos que necesito. Gracias!